# Login using auth without DB

Tags: php, laravel, saml, laravel-authentication

I trying to create laravel app where i get the login status from remote server.

For example.,

I have to two website www.xyz.com and www.abc.com

If a user is logged in on www.xyz.com, My app is www.abc.com.

When user enter www.abc.com for login i need send a request to www.xyz.com?ivtext=dgajsdgaksgdkgadcg&cyhertext=kahshasdhhakshk

From where i get response in form if user is logged in at xyz.com

```
Array ( [EMPINFO] => Array ( [EMPCODE] => 12354 [AUTHFLAG] => 1 [EMPNAME] => Foo Bar ) [MODULEINFO] => Array ( [STATIONID] => Array ( ) ) )
```

How can i integrate the above using laravel Auth.

How can i modify Auth or middleware to save the above data in auth session.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question shows fundamental misunderstanding on how HTTP works, it's not possible to help you with a simple answer. Research Single Sign On.

Comment: Best course of action in your case would be to hire an expert / company that deal with these types of situations and integration. It's obvious you've got a task that you can't perform, nor will you receive copy/paste solution from stackoverflow. I'll excuse myself, I don't want to do your work for free. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about laravel but this can be implemented in PHP[this might not be secure].

Create a `session.php` file in www.xyz.com server which will echo user id/token if the user is logged in else 0.

Now, In www.abc.com get contents of that `session.php` file using **file_get_contents()**
and check whether it is 0 or not. If not 0, log the user in with same user id/token.